# Select a different div based on the selected option from a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm stuck on showing a search bar, based on a selected option in a dropdown.

My html has the following components:

1. The style: to hide when not selected;

```
<style> 

 .form-inline{
      display: none;
  }
</style>
```

2. My dropdown with the selections;

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <select id="searchEngine" class="form-control mr-sm-2" style="background-color:#00FFFF;">
     <option value="Wolfram" >Wolfram</option>
     <option value="Approach_Zero">Approach zero</option>
     <option value="Google">Google</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

3. Then my content: my different divs that need to be shown when selected:

```
<div class="content">
              <div id="Wolfram" class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input1" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search Wolfram">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="search-button1">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div id="Approach_Zero" class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input2" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search Approach Zero">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="search-button2">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div id="Google" class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input3" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search Google">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="search-button3">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
</div>
```

4. The script that should take care of the logic:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script>
              $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#searchEngine").on('change', function(){
                  $(".form-inline").hide();
                  $("#" + $(this).val()).fadeIn(700);
                });
              });
</script>
```

But this doesn't seem to work and I can't see why. Anyone an idea what's going wrong??

**EDIT**

Based on the comments, I try to adjust the code and it works in the demo.
See below.
However(!), It doesn't work in my html but the only thing that I do differently is running the javascript in my html file. But this doesn't work for some reason. Why not??

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#searchEngine").on('change', function () {
    $(".form-inline").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).fadeIn(700);
  });
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <style> 
              nav {
              font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
              }
              .form-inline{
                display: none;
              }
            </style>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cv_index' %}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'project_index' %}">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'blog_index' %}">Blog</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <select id="searchEngine" class="form-control mr-sm-2" style="background-color:#00FFFF;">
                <option value="Wolfram" >Wolfram</option>
                <option value="Approach_Zero">Approach zero</option>
                <option value="Google">Google</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <div id="Wolfram" class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input1" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search Wolfram">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="search-button1">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div id="Approach_Zero" class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input2" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search Approach Zero">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="search-button2">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div id="Google" class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input3" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search Google">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="search-button3">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

and my code looks like this (one html file):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">

<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <style> 
              nav {
              font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
              }
              .form-inline{
                display: none;
              }
            </style>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cv_index' %}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'project_index' %}">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'blog_index' %}">Blog</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <select id="searchEngine" class="form-control mr-sm-2" style="background-color:#00FFFF;">
                <option value="Wolfram" >Wolfram</option>
                <option value="Approach_Zero">Approach zero</option>
                <option value="Google">Google</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <div id="Wolfram" class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input1" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search Wolfram">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="search-button1">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div id="Approach_Zero" class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input2" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search Approach Zero">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="search-button2">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div id="Google" class="form-inline">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="search-input3" style="width: 18rem" placeholder="Search Google">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" id="search-button3">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#searchEngine").on('change', function () {
                  $(".form-inline").hide();
                  $("#" + $(this).val()).fadeIn(700);
              });
            });
            </script>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: `.on('change', handler)` or `.change(handler)` - pick one, not both.

Comment: An id can only take a single *word* ... it is unique. Either use à class or an underscore to set `approach  zero` as a single *word* so it validates for an id value. Once this is fixed, it should be much easier to fix a bug around it.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks! I adjusted my post. Still can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: You are using jQuery slim version that doesn't include animation methods. Check errors in your browser dev tools console

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks! I'm almost there, except for the fact that running the script in my html file doesn't seem to work. Why is that? Is there something wrong? The snippet demo works fine though :s

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery twice? Also, your jquery snippet should be run near the closing `</body>` tag. That way you can ensure that the select element actually exists. If you use Dev tools in your browser, it can help debug.

Comment: @disinfor but why does it work in my snippet and not with the same code, except for the script run in the html file itself? I can run other scripts in it just fine...

Comment: Because the the snippet executes the JS field AFTER the HTML block

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("[id='" + $(this).val() + "']").fadeIn(700);
```

instead of

```
$("#" + $(this).val()).fadeIn(700);
```

Reason: The IDs contain spaces and in such cases, you can use an attribute selector. In your code, an element with id 'Approach Zero' is translated as `$("#Approach Zero")` which is a different selector altogether.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/6052/

Comment: Could there be an other reason why it still doesn't work with me?

Comment: @Steven01123581321 Not sure unless I see the full code. The demo works fine though.

Comment: I added my full code. Demo indeed works fine.

Comment: Spaces are invalid in element IDs. Creating a hack is only masking the actual problem

Comment: @charlietfl and @K K Adjusted my post.